# sorting the NSArray using date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsdateformatter

but I didn't got the current output, I want to sort the array by using date format,my array date is in string format.that data is like this

(
Fri,10 Apr,16:59 pm,
Fri,10 Apr,18:37 pm,
Fri,10 Apr,22:28 pm,
Sat,11 Apr,16:59 pm
)

so I want sort this data correctly

Comment: Date format or date?

Comment: what is the difference of both

Comment: Date is the exact date time value. But format just used for display the date. How can you compare the format?

Comment: i want same like,this formate  EE,dd MMM,HH:mm a

Comment: You said you want to sort the array, right?

Comment: Your format is wrong. You are using 24Hour style format and also using am/pm. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
NSString *str1 = @"Fri,10 Apr,16:59";
NSString *str2 = @"Fri,10 Apr,14:37";
NSString *str3 = @"Sat,11 Apr,16:59";    

NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:str1, str2, str3, nil];
arr = [arr sortedArrayUsingFunction:dateSort context:nil];

//The date sort function
NSComparisonResult dateSort(NSString *s1, NSString *s2, void *context) {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EE,dd MMM,HH:mm"];

    NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:s1];
    NSDate *d2 = [formatter dateFromString:s2];

    return [d1 compare:d2]; // ascending order
    return [d2 compare:d1]; // descending order
}
```

See result screenshot-
[image]

Comment: i am using this only dude,but some time,its not working properly

Comment: in which scenario its failing. when you are using 24hr format dont use am/pm. i have checked this with different datetime, it works fine.

Comment: @MaheshReddy - what happened? you accepted & then unaccepted this answer. what is not working properly for you?

Comment: dont know some times not properly sorting

Comment: @MaheshReddy - Dont know what kind of issue you are facing but this snippet works fine. Use either "EE,dd MMM,HH:mm" or "EE,dd MMM,hh:mm a". It should be either 24Hr format or 12Hr.

Answer (score 0):

First recheck your dateFormat. Use either "EE,dd MMM,HH:mm" or "EE,dd MMM,hh:mm a".

Then you can sort array like,

```
- (void)sortDateStrings {

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"EE,dd MMM,HH:mm"];

  // Input
  NSArray *dateStringArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fri,10 Apr,22:28", @"Sat,11 Apr,16:59", @"Fri,10 Apr,16:59", @"Fri,10 Apr,18:37", nil];

  NSArray *sortedArray = [dateStringArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
  }];

  NSLog(@"Original = %@", dateStringArray);
  NSLog(@"Sorted = %@", sortedArray);
}
```

Comment: i am using this EE,dd MMM,hh:mm a

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
NSArray *arrOfDates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Fri,10 Apr,16:59", @"Fri,10 Apr,18:37", @"Fri,10 Apr,22:28", @"Sat,11 Apr,16:59", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrOfSortedDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE,dd MMM,HH:mm"];
for(NSString *strDate in arrOfDates){
    NSDate *formattedDate = [formatter dateFromString:strDate];
    [arrOfSortedDates addObject:formattedDate];
}

[arrOfSortedDates sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```